# Resilient storage for data, on Windows

Tags: windows, hard-drive-cache, data-loss-prevention

I'm considering moving my PC workstation to a new platform, and I need to think hard what to do with my data volume.

I have a 6TB data volume, mainly for VMs and files in active use. HDDs are slow for VMs, especially multiple VMs in parallel, so I use Intel RST and configure the volume as a mirrored pair of 7200 HDDs with an SSD "write-through" cache. Surprisingly its both fast and safe - the PC has crashed numerous times over the years, but I've never lost anything as a result. Not the usual experience with soft RAID, I know.

*(I should say that I'm aware of soft RAID risks. There's a 35 TB ZFS file server too, for backups and near line storage. The 6TB is purely for routine PC use.  So I don't want to go into the pros and cons of hardware+soft RAID, assume I'm well experienced in these. Anyway as you'll see, it's moot)*

So anyhow, I want to ditch the soft raid. But I do need to keep the HDD mirror, and I do need to keep some form of SSD caching/acceleration for that mirror. So I'm considering my options, and there aren't that many. To be honest the only viable options i can come up with are fairly arcane. Hence I need advice!

## Options based on hardware/firmware RAID:

RAID in hw/fw, with a caching system and loss protection, should be good, but hasn't been so for me.

- **RAID card with RAID 1 + caching capability** - just no. Tried this with an LSI battery backed card, it was the * only * time I lost data. Disks scrambled after a crash. Hard to untangle it. Not going there again.
- **Soft RAID** (Intel RST) - works for me, but want to move away from it. No.

## Options based on a second machine or VM running (say) ZFS sharing a 6TB pool via iSCSI:

ZFS handles caching/acceleration nicely and I'm experienced with it. Its also robust and stable. Maybe put the data on ZFS on a second real or virtual machine? My main concerns here are latency (PHY based) and risk of uncontrolled pileup (VM based). Also loss of hardware access (passthrough) and the need to secure a hypervisor too.

- **iSCSI on another machine with better resilience (FreeNAS iSCSI node?)** - too slow when its over the network, and latency an issue?? Unsure.
- **Run under a hypervisor and run an iSCSI node on ZFS on another VM using dedicated pool** - avoids a chunk of latency. Wary of being over complex, or the risk of a real mess + data loss if it goes wrong.
- **Run Windows within a BSD VM (bhyve? KVM? Other?)** - easy to create and use a BSD ZFS pool in a windows VM. But GPU pass through would be needed in this case, and I don't know if that's possible. Perhaps not.

## Options based on resilient caching/acceleration within Windows itself:

Finally, there are ways to get a resilient mirror with caching/mirroring within Windows itself. I find I'm drawn to these as most likely to be my optimal solutions. But they're both untested by me.

- **Storage Spaces / ReFS**
- **ZFS on Windows**

The last 2 seem my most pragmatic options. They avoid VM and multi-machine complexity, and because they bring mirrored drives +caching/accelerating SSDs, and error correction, into Windows itself, they meet my needs. But they are both technologies I haven't tried on Windows before. They * should * both be solid. But how solid is solid? What to trust?

And that's my dilemma. Advice really appreciated - either comments/corrections on my options, or maybe entire new options too.

If more information is needed, ask! And thank you.